# How to repeat a block in a jinja2 template?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I'm using [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) as the template engine to a static HTML site generated through a Python script.

I want to repeat the content of a block in the layout template, which goes something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - {{ sitename }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</h1>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This template will be extended in a page template, that looks like this:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}Page title{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
Here goes the content
{% endblock %}
```

However, this doesn't work as I expected, resulting in an error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: block 'title' defined twice
```

Jinja interprets the second `{% block title %}` in *layout.html* as a block redefinition.

How can I repeat the content of a block in the same template using jinja2?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use the [special `self` variable](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#child-template) to access the block by name:

```
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - {{ sitename }}</title>
<!-- ... snip ... -->
<h1>{{ self.title() }}</h1>
```